# How to remove matrices in a numpy array of matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, numpy-ndarray

I have a **numpy array** `arr_seg_labs` which has the following shape: **(1735, 128, 128)**.
It contains pixel masks between 1 and 10 and also contains zeros and 255 (background).
I want to remove those (128, 128) matrices which not contain the given category identifier (9) and to keep those which contain at least one 9.
I made a mask (`horse_mask`) for this, but I don't know how can I continue this thread to filter this numpy array

```
CAT_IDX_HORSE = 9
horse_mask = arr_seg_labs == CAT_IDX_HORSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use masks and indexing as:

```
CAT_IDX_HORSE = 9
mask = (a == CAT_IDX_HORSE ).sum((1, 2))
result = a[mask != 0]
```